# Magento 2 custom product attribute

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, controllers

Need help/idea's for the following:
We have products which can be applied to different car models and car manufacturers.

So field manufacturer is multi-select, populating this field is not a problem as well as selecting correct values for a product.
The main issue is selecting the correct values for the model.

Was thinking about creating a controller and on manufacturer choice repopulate model field with applicable data.

Is this the only way or there is another solution?

Edit:
Created 2 Custom attributes with own source.
One contains all Manufacturers, second contains all Models.
Main problem is for example we have Ferrari - model 412 and we have Volkswagen model 412 as you can see both have same model name.

This problem can be solved if we add Manufacturers name before model name.
But listing through all available models to find right one is pain. So we need possibility to show only those models which are based on chosen Manufacturers.

Comment: I suggest you rephrase your question as it is not clear what issue you are facing. You might want to explain "The main issue is selecting the correct values for the model."

Comment: Edited my question.

Comment: Why don't you use configurable product. So you can add a Configurable product - Ferrari and Ferrari 412 and so on. Same way you add a t shirt with different colors and sizes

Comment: This shop will sell rims, so we can't make it configurable product. So on frontend when you filter ferrari it will show all rims for that car, then you can narrow it down by model and finally by diameter.